# com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor and com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor are in unnamed module of java.net.URLClassLoader

Tags: protocol-buffers, flink-streaming

I am getting the below error when the pyflink streaming pipeline tries to start. Source is protobuf coming from Kafka.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor cannot be cast to class
> com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor
> (com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor and
> com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor are in unnamed module of
> loader java.net.URLClassLoader @1a89e2c2)

Below is the code I running:

```
kafka_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                 'flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.0.1-1.18.jar')
protobuf_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                    'flink-sql-protobuf-1.18.0.jar')
flink_common_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                        'flink-table-common-1.18.0.jar')
flink_core_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                      'flink-core-1.18.0.jar')
accounts_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                    'flink-kafka-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
google_protobuf_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                           'protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar')
tbl_env.get_config()\
            .set("execution.checkpointing.mode", "EXACTLY_ONCE") \
            .set("execution.checkpointing.interval", "3min") \
            .set("restart-strategy.type", "fixed-delay") \
            .set("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts", "3") \
            .set("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay", "30s") \
            .set("pipeline.jars", f"file://{kafka_jar};file://{protobuf_jar};file://{flink_common_jar};file://{flink_core_jar};file://{accounts_jar};file://{google_protobuf_jar}")

tbl_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE accounts_topic_manual_adjustment (
        id BIGINT
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'accounts',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'xxxxx',
        'properties.group.id' = 'accountsaf',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
        'format' = 'protobuf',
        'protobuf.message-class-name' = '.account.AccountModel',
        'protobuf.ignore-parse-errors' = 'false'
    )
""")
```

Update:
Error is coming from the generated class of the protobuf but not sure how to tackle it.